# Proxy Classes for JSON-RPC web service of web2py

Tags: python, web2py, json-rpc

I have developed JSON-RPC web service in Web2py. It operates on objects of classes which are defined by me. It accepts two objects and returns a result of custom defined type. I want to generate proxy classes to communicate with this web service. I know there are libraries to create proxy classes from WSDL but how can I do the same for JSON web services. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many internets ago, there was a proposal for a WSDL-like specification for JSON-RPC (and similar protocols) called [Service Mapping Description](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/03/19/pluggable-web-services-with-smd/). (see also [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/rpc/smd.html)).

Most of the links describing it are now defunct. Google returns some discussion group postings, but not much else. Dojo toolkit did a reasonable implementation of the [client-side part](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/rpc/Service.html) of an implementation.

Server-side implementations are even rarer.

Good luck :-(

**PS**: json-rpc is *super* simple. What aweful endpoints are you dealing with that you need to auto-generate client-side proxies?